# lxml - use default class element lookup and TreeBuilder parser target at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

With lxml, is there a way to use a `ElementDefaultClassLookup` and a parser `target` derived from the `TreeBuilder` class at the same time?

I have tried:

```
from lxml import etree

class MyElement(etree.ElementBase):
    pass

class MyComment(etree.CommentBase):
    pass

class MyTreeBuilder(etree.TreeBuilder):
    pass

parser_lookup = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup(element=MyElement, comment=MyComment)
parser = etree.XMLParser(target=MyTreeBuilder()) # (My)TreeBuilder accepts a `parser` argument keyword (which will then use the class lookup from that parser), but we haven't created the parser yet!
parser.set_element_class_lookup(parser_lookup)

xml_string = '<root xmlns:test="hello"><element test:foobar="1" /><!-- world --></root>'

root = etree.fromstring(xml_string, parser=parser)
print(type(root), type(root.xpath('//comment()[1]')[0]), etree.tostring(root))
```

which results in:

```
<class 'lxml.etree._Element'> <class 'lxml.etree._Comment'> b'<root><element xmlns:ns0="hello" ns0:foobar="1"/><!-- world --></root>'
```

I want:

```
<class 'MyElement'> <class 'MyComment'> b'<root xmlns:test="hello"><element test:foobar="1"/><!-- world --></root>'
```

Notice the XML namespace differences as well as the Python classes.

I'm using lxml `3.4.4`.

---

I can get the correct namespace prefix on the attribute by using:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(target=etree.TreeBuilder())
```

which doesn't make any sense to me - why doesn't my derived class behave the same way? (I realize that omitting the `target` argument will by default use a `TreeBuilder` anyway.)

and I can get the correct class and namespace prefix by using:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser()
```

but I specifically want to use my own "`target`" to create a tree, and ideally don't want to have to reinvent the wheel.

I have tried to set the `target` after the parser is initialized, like so:

```
parser.target = MyTreeBuilder(parser=parser)
```

but this gives an error:

> AttributeError: attribute 'target' of 'lxml.etree._BaseParser' objects is not writable

I checked the [source code for the TreeBuilder class](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/saxparser.pxi#L631), and tried:

```
class MyTreeBuilder(etree.TreeBuilder):
    def set_parser(self, parser):
        super()._parser = parser

parser_lookup = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup(element=MyElement, comment=MyComment)
tb = MyTreeBuilder()
parser = etree.XMLParser(target=tb)
parser.set_element_class_lookup(parser_lookup)
tb.set_parser(parser)
```

which gives:

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_parser'

and I tried:

```
parser_lookup = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup(element=MyElement, comment=MyComment)
fake_parser = etree.XMLParser()
fake_parser.set_element_class_lookup(parser_lookup)
tb = MyTreeBuilder(parser=fake_parser)
parser = etree.XMLParser(target=tb)
parser.set_element_class_lookup(parser_lookup)
```

which gives the correct classes, but not still the correct attribute namespaces.  I therefore imagine it needs some information from the correct parser to be able to build the tree correctly.

I tried setting the `element_factory` keyword argument instead of, and as well as, `parser` - but got the same result:

```
tb = MyTreeBuilder(element_factory=fake_parser.makeelement)
# and
tb = MyTreeBuilder(element_factory=fake_parser.makeelement, parser=fake_parser)
```

---

EDIT: looking at the [lxml class lookup code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/classlookup.pxi#L35), it seems that one can set a class attribute called PARSER on the custom Element.

I tried that:

```
MyElement.PARSER = parser
```

but the result was the same as without it.

However, the `makeelement` method of the parser works as expected:

```
test = parser.makeelement('root', attrib={ '{hello}foobar': '1' }, nsmap={ 'test': 'hello' })
print(type(test), etree.tostring(test))
```

as it gives (obviously the attribute is on a different node than when I parse the string):

```
<class 'MyElement'> b'<root xmlns:test="hello" test:foobar="1"/>'
```

Combining these two approaches using:

```
def m(tag, attrib=None,nsmap=None, *children):
    return MyElement.PARSER.makeelement(tag, attrib=attrib, nsmap=nsmap, *children)

parser = etree.XMLParser(target=MyTreeBuilder(element_factory=m))
```

gives the correct classes but still incorrect namespaces.

---

Is what I want possible?  Why do the namespaces "go wrong" as soon as I use a custom target that isn't a pure TreeBuilder?  Is there something I need to do differently somewhere, to manually correct the namespace behavior?  Will I have to make my own tree builder implementation?